# Elasticsearch SQL query issue with 'CASE WHEN' using with 'WHERE IN'

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I am trying to execute this query

```
 SELECT 
     id, 
     CASE 
         WHEN name LIKE 'John' THEN name 
     END AS name 
 FROM 
     Employee 
 WHERE 
     id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

but I am getting an error:

> details: "Failed to parse operator [LIKE]"
> reason: "Invalid SQL query"
> type: "SqlParseException"

However I am getting proper response for these queries,

```
SELECT
    id, 
    CASE WHEN name LIKE 'John' THEN name END AS name 
FROM
    Employee
```

or

```
SELECT id 
FROM Employee 
WHERE id IN ('1', '2', '3')
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Sumesh